# Counting number of taps on a button using C# for WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button

I want to develop an app for WP7 using C# where a user taps a button as much as he can within 10 seconds and each tap will carry 2 points. While tapping itself, I want the increment in the total to be display in a textbox. Please help!

Comment: Didn't quite get what is your question...

Comment: Just increase the value of a variable each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML :-

```
                <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Tap Me"
                        Click="Button_Click" />
                <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" />
            </StackPanel>
```

The C# :-

```
        private int count = 0;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        this.MyTextBox.Text = count.ToString();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The above code works fine but i want a timer for 30 seconds and after the timer completes, the button should be disabled.